# change color in ListView

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am trying to change the border background when a `Listview` item is `selected`.

```
<Border x:Name="myback" Background="Transparent">
     <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I wonder if the Border is inside the template of the ListViewItem, if so please go to the following path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml** to get all the default style for all the UWP controls.
Then please search for the ListViewItem style, you will find two ListViewItem style, Please copy the the style which is named as **ListViewItemExpanded** to your project and add your Border in side the **ListViewItemExpanded** style.

After that in order to change the Border Background when a ListViewItem is selected, please search for the **Selected/PointerOverSelected/PressedSelected** VisualState and add the following XAML code inside it for changing color:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myback" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```